# Solidity: How can I access a variable dynamically by name?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, state-variable

Is there a way to access variables in solidity using another variable?

Something like this:

```
contract Test {
    uint age;
    string varAge = "age";

    function setAge() public {
        // varAge should be able to access age variable
       ${varAge} = 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mapping to access through a specific key and modify its value.
Example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
    uint age;
    string varAge = "age";
    // Map string key with relative value
    mapping(string=>uint) mapAges;

    // Setter age
    function setAge() public {
        mapAges[varAge] = 30;
    }

    // Getter age
    function getAge() external view returns(uint) {
        return mapAges[varAge];
    }

}
```